# Functional integral, the sum over all possible paths?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, path-integral, integration

I have a question about the interpretation of a functional.

I consider for now the discrete case of functional integration (instead of the continuous case).

A functional integral is:
$$ \int\mathcal{D}\left[x\right] =  \prod_{n}^{}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx_{n}$$
where $x$ depends on $t$, i.e. $x_{n} \equiv x\left(t_{n}\right)$.

My interpretation goes as follows, we can plot a grid, the horizontal axis is time $t$ axis and the vertical axis is the position $x$ axis. Draw a bunch of vertical lines intersecting with the time axis. The vertical lines are labeled by $t_{0}$, $t_{1}$, $t_{2}$ and so on.

We are integrating over each of these lines from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$. In other words, we are summing the values along each vertical line for each integral. In the end we multiply all the integrals. My question is, how does this corresponds to summing over all paths?

Comment: Are you asking heuristically or rigorously?

Comment: Asking for heuristically.

Comment: I have never, ever seen a rigid definition of a "path integral" (as "integrating over all possible paths" as opposed to the common "integral along a given path").